# windows 2012 wierd samba error

Tags: windows-server-2012, samba, openldap

so today I set up a new fileserver and auth server running samba. I have already connected both unix systems to the ldap(that it's also running) and have connected 2 windows 2003 servers to the samba auth. The weird problem come when i try to connect my windows 2012 server to the samba. It give me this error:

```
An Active Domain Controller for the domain "mosek.intranet" could not be contacted

dns query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.mosek.intranet

the following domain controllers were indentified by the query:
fredericia
however no domain controllers could be contacted
```

I find this funny, because all other windows versions works fine (I have also tested 2008) 
I encountered this problem before in testing, but the solution was to add these lines to my smb.conf:

```
domain master = yes
local master = yes
```

Do someone have a fix for this? I'm almost sure that it's just a line or 2 in the smb.conf that needs to be added, just like my previous fix for the problem, so that newer versions of windows will know that my server is a domain controller.

to help you out to a posibble solution i have a new data:
my auth server is running ubuntu 14.04
the server i'm trying to join is a windwos server 2012

my smb.conf looks like this:

```
[global]
    workgroup = MOSEK.INTRANET
    netbios name = FREDERICIA
    server string = MOSEK PDC

    deadtime = 10

    log level = 1
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 5000
    debug pid = yes
    debug uid = yes
    syslog = 0
    utmp = yes

    security = user
    domain logons = yes
    domain master = yes
    local master = yes
    preferred master = yes
    os level = 255
    logon path =
    logon home =
    logon drive = x:
    logon script = \\fredericia\logon\logon.bat
    acl allow execute always = True

    passdb backend = ldapsam:"ldap://fredericia.mosek.intranet/"
    ldap ssl = off
    ldap admin dn = cn=admin,dc=mosek,dc=intranet
    ldap delete dn = no

    ## Sync UNIX password with Samba password
    ## Method 1:
    ldap password sync = yes
    ## Method 2:
    ;ldap password sync = no
    ;unix password sync = yes
    ;passwd program = /usr/sbin/smbldap-passwd -u '%u'
    ;passwd chat = "Changing *\nNew password*" %n\n "*Retype new password*"$

    ldap suffix = dc=mosek,dc=intranet
    ldap user suffix = ou=Users
    ldap group suffix = ou=Groups
    ldap machine suffix = ou=Computers
    ldap idmap suffix = ou=Idmap

    add user script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-useradd -m '%u' -t 1
    rename user script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-usermod -r '%unew' '%uold'
    delete user script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-userdel '%u'
    set primary group script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-usermod -g '%g' '%u'
    add group script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-groupadd -p '%g'
    delete group script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-groupdel '%g'
    add user to group script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-groupmod -m '%u' '%g'
    delete user from group script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-groupmod -x '%u' '%g'
    add machine script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-useradd -w '%u' -t 1

[NETLOGON]
    path = /space/logon
    browseable = no
    share modes = no

[PROFILES]
    path = /var/lib/samba/profiles
    browseable = no
    writeable = yes
    create mask = 0611
    directory mask = 0700
    profile acls = yes
    csc policy = disable
    map system = yes
    map hidden = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the version of Samba.
You can add version 1 by opening powershell. Type `Add-WindowsFeature FS-SMB1`. Reboot. Some people say it can take up to 10 min after reboot to fully initialize.

You can use the powershell command `Get SMBConnection` to see version info as well.

EDIT....

If this is 2012R2 then.....

This may be a helpful link  [Samba in Server 2012 R2](http://woshub.com/smb-1-0-support-in-windows-server-2012-r2/)

Here is a statement from this site. ..

If Windows 2012 R2 is used as a domain controller, it means that Windows XP / Server 2003 clients won’t be able to execute logon scripts (NETLOGON) and run some of the group policies stored in the network folders on the domain controllers.

Comment: The server said at no features FS-SMB1 was, found but i tried enableling smb1 protocol and disable smb2 protocol with the samme xobfiguration in power Shell, but still no cigar

Comment: I added this link above. It may be helpful. http://woshub.com/smb-1-0-support-in-windows-server-2012-r2/

Comment: I will look into it, though the link is for when windows is a DC, but in my case the windows machine is a client for a Linux DC

Comment: I have locked through the link, and i can confirm that the windows server is configured like the link explained

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought it was a new DC. What linux distro is your DC.

Comment: as stated in the question: 'my auth server is running ubuntu 14.04'
I have used this tutorial, to set up my samba: http://www.unixmen.com/setup-samba-domain-controller-with-openldap-backend-in-ubuntu-13-04/

Comment: I'm not trying to insult you here, just trying to think simple.

Comment: Opps, hit enter too soon. Can you ping both ways and have you tried turning the windows firewall off?

Comment: yes of course, sorry if I sounded harsh :) I meant no offense

yes I can ping both ways, both with host name and FQDN, both works perfectly.

Comment: Not at all,  that was supposed to be one message. And, I should have read that again before asking. Server 2012 is more secure and may require more srv dns records. I'll do some research when I get time.

Comment: hmm I researched a bit my self, and I find it funny. when i try to do an nslookup from the windows server to _LDAP._TCP.DC._MSDCS.mosek.intranet
I get the dns servers name and ip, and not the auth server. Could it be this causing the problem?

Comment: If you do ipconfig /all on one of your server 2003 machines and on the 2012 machine are they using the settings for dns servers?

Comment: Oh, and yes, I think the record is resolving to the wrong server.

Comment: If the DHCP settings are the same try setting the auth server dns to 127.0.0.1 and secondary to blank.                         If none of those work did you try the items from the Unixmen page you used to set this up. There are a couple solutions for win 7 that would probably work in 2012. If you open the page and search 'dns' you'll find it.

Comment: This link shows the requires dns records for AD https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727055.aspx